# Rails / ActionMailer alternatives to SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, actionmailer

A client's IT department is telling me that SMTP isn't secure enough for sending mail through their Exchange server from a Rails app I built (hosted on Heroku). This seems like crazy talk to me, but still, I need to find alternatives. Are there any other protocols that would work with Rails and ActionMailer that I should investigate for sending mail? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that is crazy talk. Personally, I'd point out that SMTP is the normal way for one computer to send an email to another computer. It supports transport security (`STARTTLS`) and authentication; you can even mix them (client certificates). If that's not good enough, I'd make their IT department suggest alternatives. You can hook ActionMailer into lots of things, but since "no SMTP" is pretty arbitrary, there's no way to be sure the next thing you pick will be any better.

Comment: Thanks for the input. They asked about MAPI, but I couldn't find any info about that being supported by ActionMailer.

Comment: This is probably not about sending mail TO their server, it's about sending mail THROUGH their server to other recipients. They would have to add your server to "allow relay" list, which most IT departments don't like to do. Since it's your clients own team, let them figure out the best solution, they can allow your app to send mail through, pay for 3rd party service, stand up another relay only server in a dmz, or whatever they are comfortable doing.